# Where is "encrypt my home folder" in Juno?

Tags: release-juno

During installation process in Juno, there's no longer an option to encrypt my home folder. I wonder why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It was removed in Ubuntu 18.04. Now, you can encrypt the whole Elementary Installation, which is much saver ... i think.